# TV show wants to use a photograph — what should I charge?

Tags: pricing

A television show (sit-com) wants to use an image that I took of a model.  This image would probably be on screen for a few seconds and probably part of a portfolio book that is being looked through.  I want to charge something for the usage of this image.  Could anyone help me with information on what is a good rate?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'll ge the ball rolling with some maybe-not-pertinent questions.  What kind of show is it, meaning what's their likely budget for this kind of thing?  They're probably hoping to get away with something like $5, but if the show has 5 million viewers a week, they could probably part with more.

Comment: This would be for the pilot episode of a new show.  Producers are from Sex and the City.

Comment: I've never done anything like this, but I would expect that the difference between $5 and $500 is nothing to a TV show. They spend more than that on coffee. $5000 and they might have to think.

Comment: $500 was around what I was considering, but this isn't really based on any information.  Just numbers that I was throwing around in my head.

Comment: May I ask which show?

Comment: Sorry Nick, I honestly do not know the name of it.

Comment: Some people would *pay* large amounts of money for their work to appear in a TV show.  Advertisers, for example.

Answer (score 15):

Pricing is all about the market; if the show is going to be syndicated nationally/internationally/etc.

I can't see anything directly relevant in my local friendly price guides, but had this been for TV advertising, then 985 USD would've been the price I'd have suggested.

It might be worth asking if they had a budget in mind, and start negotiating between there and what you think it's worth. Worth bearing in mind, with all photography shots, you'll need to stay below the cost of repeating the shot, if you want them to buy *your* shot.

Comment: Thank you Rowland for the insight and information.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: +1 for the *you'll need to stay below the cost of repeating the shot*